# UI-Router injector module error

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router'])
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
   // $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateprovider
    //Home states and nested views
    
            .state('home',{
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'index.html'
            })
            
           
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Modern Business - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
   
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-include='"templates/header.html"'></div>
    <div ui-view></div>
     <div ng-include='"templates/footer.html"'></div>
    
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
     <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
    <!-- Do not edit these files! In order to set the email address and subject line for the contact form go to the bin/contact_me.php file. -->
    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my HTML and app.js I am working with UIRouter. I am getting an error of injector module, but unable to figure it out. I am new to AngularJS, so please help me out. And yes, my ng-include too is not working. No results are displayed when I run my index.html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wbbmkBl6J66DuHWtJNFb?p=preview)

The casing is essential. It is `$stateProvider` not *$stateprovider*. This must be the state def:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
  //$stateprovider
  $stateProvider
   //Home states and nested views
    .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    //templateUrl: 'index.html'
    template: "<h1>hello from home</h1>",
  })
});
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wbbmkBl6J66DuHWtJNFb?p=preview)

NOTE: when you develop... do NOT use min versions. Only full can give you nice and easy to understand exceptions...

Comment: That is great to see, enjoy amazing UI-Router ;)

Answer (score 1):

`$stateprovider` should be `$stateProvider`